# Is the Stokes-Carten theorem suitable for knotted manifolds

Tags: manifolds, parametric, stokes-theorem

I am currently trying to discretise a torus knot onto a square lattice grid.

My method of achieving this has been to first use the [Torus knot parametric equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus_knot), then define a circle that follows the torus knot path using the normal and binormal, similarly to that done in [this prior question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91444/what-is-parameterization-of-the-trefoil-knot-surface-in-r%C2%B3).

Using this method, *should* have yielded me the surface of the knot, which when computed using Sympy, gives the following image of a [trefoil surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIMaG.png). So I am assuming I have done this correctly.

However, I now need to discretise the volume enclosed by this surface. My method of choice would be to pick a point and test if it exists within the surface. [This previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019260/how-can-you-determine-if-a-point-is-inside-a-parametric-2d-manifold) suggests using the Stokes-Cartan theorem to perform this, and would at the surface appear to be a good solution.

However, I have vague memories of a lecture I attended that suggested this only applies to "simple" enclosed surfaces that do not overlap.

Hence: **Is the Stokes-Carten theorem suitable for knotted manifolds**

Comment: You are misremembering.